# Physical constraint on loss function in a neural network

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm asking my question by designing a simple problem:

Considering I want to train a neural network, I know that the data follows the y=x^2 equation.

Now, I want to feed the NN two data points (for instance, [2,4] and [10, 100])

By having this dataset, if I run the neural network, it absolutely doesn't know the exact behavior of the data to predict other data. (the data is limited)

As I did research ([Link](https://medium.com/@john.l.tauscher/from-the-edge-physically-constrained-neural-networks-a5fa4812b54a)), by adding constraint inside the loss function, the code should learn the behavior of the input data. So, I added the `torch.mean((y_pred - x_real**2)**2)` constraint to the loss function. So the new loss function is:

```
loss =  criterion(y_pred, y_real) + torch.mean((y_pred - x_real**2)**2)
```

But still, the code couldn't fit and follow y=x^2 behavior even inside the data range.

I tried running the code just by removing `criterion(y_pred, y_real)`, but the code does not converge.

I wonder why this doesn't work because it's like PINN. I'm trying to tell the network how data behaves but the code doesn't understand. Am I making any mistake?

Comment: Can you add some information about your dataset? Because it could be a scaling probem

Comment: The two mentioned points as my training dataset and the points between them as the test dataset like np.linspace(2., 10., num=20)

Comment: That "constraint" is not a constraint, and it adds nothing, as presumably `y_real` is already `x**2` anyway. You just have the same loss twice. If you _know_ the relation is `y = x**2`, just use that instead of training a neural network.

Comment: Thanks @xdurch0, You're right. Do you think that adding the derivative of the `y=x**2`, `(y'=2*x)` is a good idea as the constraint? And how can I add it? Since all of the `y_real`, `x_real`, and `y_pred` are transformed using  RobustScaler, how can I add this `(y'=2*x)`? When I'm using `inverse_transfor`, all of the grads and their history are forgotten...

Answer (score 1):

DL models are data-driven ones. They strongly depend on the training data. It's strange to tyo train a NN with just two samples and test it on more.
More strange if you want to fit a quadratic curve with two observation, because there are infinite parabolas that fit that point. From a mathematical point of you you have to define at least one more point. From an implementation point of view, the more you add, the better the fit. In pytorch you can do something like this:

```
data_points = torch.tensor([[2, 4], [10, 100], ... [more points] ...])
```

Comment: I know what you mean, to solve this problem I added physical constraint. based on the paper link that I provided, it looks like it should be able to predict

Comment: I wanted to give a sneak peek of the behavior of the data to the network